# attempt to invoke gettime on a null object reference

Tags: java, time, timestamp

I am trying to get the time of today's date at 11:59 in milliseconds using a timestamp. This is what I have tried. Now this code is working fine in one device but not in the other.  It gives the error

```
 E/test: printstacktrace
                                                            java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "29/04/2017 11:59:59 PM" (at offset 20)
                                                                at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)
                                                                at curieo.android.zenmaster.mainfragments.HomeFragment$8.onDataChange(HomeFragment.java:723)
                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

.

```
  String currentDate = questiondateFormat.format(new Date(timeStampLong));
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");

            Date d = null;
            try {
                d = sdf.parse(currentDate + " " + "11:59:59 PM");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(d);

            long time = c.getTimeInMillis();

            long difference = time - timeStampLong;
            countDownTimer.start(difference);
```

Comment: Add the full stacktrace.

Comment: @QuoVadis made the changes please check

Comment: @SaranshAgarwal It works fine. check here.https://ideone.com/ARXf2n

Comment: This is most likely a local problem. Use local as show below: `SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(newPattern, Locale.US);` It should take care of it.